# Piping output of zypper ps -sss into systemctl restart

Tags: systemd, pipe, zypper, systemctl

I do not want to restart the server after a `zypper up`. Instead I want to restart all services using deleted files as shown by `zypper ps -sss`.

I thought I could do something like `zypper ps -sss | tr '\n' ' ' | systemctl restart` which fails with

> Too few arguments.

I've also tried to write into a file and use it as input `systemctl restart < myfile.txt` with the same result.

I ended up using

```
systemctl restart $(zypper ps -sss | tr '\n' ' ')
```

So two questions:

1) How can I pipe values into systemctl?

2) Is there a better way to restart all services shown by `zypper ps`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) How can I pipe values into `systemctl`?

You can't, `systemctl restart` takes the unit names as arguments, not from standard input. There's nothing wrong with that, since you have convenient ways to collect the unit names and pass them as arguments (namely `$(...)`) rather than through a pipe.

> 2) Is there a better way to restart all services shown by `zypper ps`?

Not really. Well, there's a minor improvement in that you don't really need the `tr` command, since using unquoted `$(...)` will give you multiple arguments, using any whitespace as separator. So this should be enough:

```
systemctl restart $(zypper ps -sss)
```